# What is the difference between KeyListeners and KeyBinders?

Tags: java, swing, keyboard, keylistener

Title pretty much sums it up. I'm new to using the keyboard with programs, and want to know what makes them different, which one is easier to use, etc.

Comment: Please ask a question we can definitively answer. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @TomCammann Oh forget it. I'll just delete this post.

Comment: In general, use Key Bindings with Swing apps, not KeyListeners. The tutorials will explain all.

Comment: KeyBindings offer the advantage that it handles properly issues with focus component, its ancerstors and children while keylistener work only on focused components. Morerover they simplify the reuse of a same action for different situations. Basically, you should always use KeyBindings. In some case, for example for text component, you may be tempted to use KeyListener, but there are other interfaces for that, such as DocumentListener in that case.

Comment: @Computerology Personally, I don't find anything wrong with the question, it just may not suited for SO, but since 99% of issues relating to key events revolve around people using `KeyListener`s when they should be using Key Bindings, I welcome it.

Comment: Thanks guys. And sorry for the poor question..I was just curious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`KeyListener` is the original mechanism used by AWT and Swing to allow components to register interest in key events.  It is a low level API, which provides considerable information about the key event (like modifiers).

This method of monitoring key events is discouraged under most circumstance for a number of reasons.  The first is the fact that in order for a component to receive key events (via this API) it must be focusable and have current keyboard focus.  This is a trap that 99% of questions about `KeyListeners` relate to.

The second relates to how the code looks, traditionally, using `KeyListener` would require you to have a large `if-else` statement, taking into account the various key strokes and their potential modifiers, which could become cumbersome over time - the same criticism could be leveled at `ActionListener` as well.

Key Bindings is a newer API (and is part of a larger input binding API) that can be used to monitor for very specific key events.  This includes the individual key stroke and modifiers.

The Key Bindings also use the [Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) API, which means you can reuse the `Action` in many different parts of your program without the need to re-implement the logic each time.

From [How to use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

> An alternative to key bindings is using key listeners. Key listeners
>   have their place as a low-level interface to keyboard input, but for
>   responding to individual keys key bindings are more appropriate and
>   tend to result in more easily maintained code. Key listeners are also
>   difficult if the key binding is to be active when the component
>   doesn't have focus. Some of the advantages of key bindings are they're
>   somewhat self documenting, take the containment hierarchy into
>   account, encourage reusable chunks of code (Action objects), and allow
>   actions to be easily removed, customized, or shared. Also, they make
>   it easy to change the key to which an action is bound. Another
>   advantage of Actions is that they have an enabled state which provides
>   an easy way to disable the action without having to track which
>   component it is attached to.

Comment: Thanks. This is all I wanted to know. Sorry for a poor question.

Comment: As I said, I don't think the question is a poor one, I actually like it, it just might not be suited SO.  There are a lot of people who could learn from this question, and I will be linking back to when they post questions about why there `KeyListener` doesn't work.  While strictly not a SO question, I think people need to have a little more lee-way when it comes to a good question regardless.